# sleep boost::thread indefinitely and wake from another thread?

Tags: c++, linux, boost, concurrency, thread-sleep

Is it possible to have a `boost::thread` sleep indefinitely after its work is completed and then wake it from another `boost::thread`?

Using `while(1)`s are perfect for a dedicated server where I want the threads to run all cores at 100%, but I'm writing a websocket++ server to be run on a desktop, thus I only want the `boost::thread`s to run when they actually have work to do, so I can do other work on my desktop without performance suffering.

I've seen other examples where `boost::thread`s are set to `sleep()` for constant a amount of time, but I'd rather not spend the time trying to find that optimal constant; besides, I need the websocket++ server to respond as quickly as possible when it receives data to process.

If this is possible, how can it be done with multiple threads trying to wake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This mechanism is implemented by what is called a condition-variable, see [boost::condition_variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref). Essentially, the waiting thread will sleep on a locked mutex until another thread signals the condition, thereby unlocking it.

Watch out for spurious wake-ups. Sometimes the waiting thread will wake-up without being signaled. This means that you should still put a while-loop that checks a predicate (or condition) to decipher between real wake-ups and spurious ones.

Answer (score 1):

yes, pthread_mutex_t+pthread_cond_t is the right thing to use, you can find the corresponding
 thing in boost.